# Open html file to bookmark

Tags: java, browser, uri

I'm trying to open a local HTML file from within my Java application and open it to a specific bookmark. I can successfully create the URI and open the browser, and it brings up the correct file, but does not go to the bookmark like I need it to.

If I type the following into the browser's address bar, I get the file and bookmark needed:

```
file:///D:/MyHTMLFile#MyBookmark
```

Here is the code I've tried that is not working - it just opens the file, but not the specific bookmark:

```
        URI rui = URI.create("file:///D:/MyHTMLFile#MyBookmark");
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(rui);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What is the correct way to open a browser to a specific bookmark within a local file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem, but didn't find any solution with the URI approach.

But if you don't mind to modify a file, here's a workaround using JavaScript:

First, you need to have a .js file (let's call him GoTo.js), looking like that :

```
let htmlBookmark = "";

function goTo() {
    let as = document.getElementsByName(htmlBookmark);
    as.forEach(a => a.scrollIntoView());
}
```

Then, your .html file needs to call the function goTo() specified in the GoTo.js file when it is loaded, something like that:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="GoTo.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="goTo()">
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

The src="GoTo.js" implies that your .html file and your .js file are in the same folder.

Finally, instead of calling the bookmark, your java application just needs to modify the .js file to put the wanted bookmark in the *htmlBookmark* field, and then open this .html file, something like:

```
private static void updateBookmarkHTML(String newBookMark) {
    File goTo = new File("yourGoToFile.js");
    Path path = goTo.toPath();
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;//Or UTF_8
    try {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
        //Regex to replace the old bookMark to the new bookMark
        content = content.replaceAll("(let htmlBookmark = \")(.*)\";", "$1" + newBookMark + "\";");

        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void displayHelp(String newBookMark){
    updateBookmarkHTML(newBookMark);
    URI uri = URI.create("file:///D:/MyHTMLFile");
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayHelp("MyBookmark");
}
```

This will open your html file at the specified bookmark. But again, you will need to modify a file to do so, so this solution is situational.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Will look into this more.